# How to build a MySQL query with conditional filters?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, filter

I'm pretty new to both PHP and MySQL and I'm trying to build a small library of singers'  quotes. I'd like the user to be able to search for a quote by typing a part of the quote itself, the singer's name or the singer's band, if any.

Now, that part I pretty much nailed:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE (quote LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR singerName LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR bandName LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%")';
```

This works, although it alors returns results where the search_string is in the middle of a word: if I type "her", it will return every quote containing "other" or "together". If I drop the second % from the query, it won't return quotes where the search_string isn't the very first word, which I want it to do.

Anyway, what I'd also like to do is give the possibility to filter the results. Let's say I want the user to be able to only show quotes in English, German or Both, via radio buttons. By default, Both is selected, so the $query above is still valid. However, if the user selects English, it should also say something like `AND (language = 'EN')`.

For now, I tried adding to the query this way:

```
if ($_POST['language']== "EN") {
  $sql .= " AND (language = 'EN')";
}
```

It works, but it can be a real hassle, as I also want the user to search for quotes using only the filters, without entering a search query: they would be able to look for quotes in English by singers in Band, for example. So, I also have this:

```
if (strlen($search_string) < 1) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM quotes";
}
```

But then, the `$sql .= " AND (language = 'EN')";` wouldn't be correct anymore, as "AND" should be "WHERE". So I'll have to have another if clause to modify the string, and another one for every filter I decide to apply.

My question is then: how should I build my query, given that there are *optional* filters, and that the search should also be possible using the filters *alone*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set an always true condition in order to have constant `WHERE` clause.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE 1 = 1 "
if (true) {
    $sql .= " AND col1 LIKE '%val%' ";
}
```

Comment: Moreover if you dont want to use like you can use regexp check out https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html This way you can exclude unwanted search results