# Checkbox filters on search results with strictly PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, search

I'm creating a basic book review page for a class I'm currently taking. I've been able to accomplish simple searches from my Database:

```
$search_request = "SELECT * 
                   FROM books 
                   WHERE author
                   LIKE '%$searchfor%' COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI 
                   OR title LIKE '%$searchfor%' COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI";
```

This results in a perfectly fine request and answer.

However, this just provides me with a list of the books. I would like to filter the search results.

Say someone searches "Tolkien", then I would like to have two checkboxes: Authors and Books, where they could filter the Tolkien search to display authors named Tolkien or Books including Tolkien.

As long as I have some way of recieving a input which indicates either author and books, I will have no problem writing up the sql query to achieve it.

I've tried with both `$_GET` through an anchor and `$_POST` with an additional form, however the GET and the POST overwrite my existing POST with the initial search. Is there a way to do this strictly with PHP or very simple JS?

Comment: Why not offer that filter in the initial form, instead of waiting for them to search and then offering to filter?

Comment: That is my back up plan. However, I want to make it so that it can work on more extensive databases and be more dynamic. Say I also have 'Tags' and 'Genres', and someone searches King. I woud like the search to be preselected as Books, showing books that has King in it. But then be able to toggle Tags, to show the tags with King in it, and then Authors with King in it etc.

Comment: I still can't see why, for that, you wouldn't simply have a form with several fields - the search text and then a list of categories (such as "books", "author", "tags", "genre") as checkboxes) they can choose from to apply the search text to. It's more user-friendly to offer the user the ability to select exactly what they want up-front. The two-step process just seems to a) slow the user down, and b) result in unnecessary load on your server (because they would end up running two queries when they only really needed one).

Comment: Yeah, I guess you are right. I opted for that option, having two radiobuttons inside the same form as the search field. Thanks for the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

You could make your sql query conditional. That is, only append the `WHERE` clause after a *certain condition* is true. Certain condition could mean adding a query parameter to the request url. e.g get/request/route?filter="author". If the url's query parameter `filter` is not empty, you can check if the value matches either `author` or `title` and then append a corresponding `WHERE` clause. E.g

```
 $sql .= 
  WHERE author
   LIKE '%$searchfor%' COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI
```

Else if there isn't any filter just append both `WHERE` clauses, this time using the `OR` as you have done above.

You may find this question helpful [How to build a MySQL query with conditional filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185932/how-to-build-a-mysql-query-with-conditional-filters)

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  However, I opted for just including the 'filter' radiobuttons inside the same form as the search, as I found out that suited my needs well enough.